# SSRS bar chart custom grid line color with expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a bar chart, the values are percentage. I want the 100% grid line to be a standout color like blue rather than the default grayish "Gainsboro".

I tried to use expression for the line color in "Chart Gridlines" dialog, but how do I know "current" line is 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a strip line, we can do it.

1. Select Value Axis
2. Click "StripLines"
3. Click "Add"
4. Set "BackgroundColor" and "BorderColor" you want.
5. Set "BorderWidth" so make it standout, I set it to 2pt.
6. Set "IntervalOffset". I set it to 1 because I want 100% is the target (1 = 100%).
7. do NOT change "StripWidth" otherwise it will not acurately aligned on the number you want!

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a hack but how about adding a series with all 100% for each data point, then you could choose the colour of the series and make it as thick and as dark as you want

Comment: mmm... I did more research, it seems that I can use strip line. but I cannot have it displayed, I struggled with the IntervalOffset and I can't work it out.

Comment: Ok, I finally managed to do it by adding a strip line, set  BackgroundColor, StripWidth and it works